Listen on multiple input tags and concatenate inputs to a single output field without need to click a button
With plain JavaScript + HTML, I would like to listen on multiple inputs including a <select>-tag and generate an output text field (which can be copied) without the need to click on a button. If possible, I would like to add the "copy-to-clipboard" sign and functionality to the right of the output text field (e.g. Guthub Pages often provide such a possibility).
Here is the link to fiddle to test and verify what I wrote.
I am looking for:
Some eventListening-mechanic which concatenates input fields to an output string which is displayed and ready to be copied.


function fun() {
  var fn = document.getElementById("fname");
  var ln = document.getElementById("lname");
  var test = document.getElementById("test");
  out = ln.value + "," + fn.value + "," + test.value;
  document.getElementById("out0").innerHTML = out;
  switch (test.value) {
    default: var val = "XXX"
    break;
    case "A":
        var val = "YYY"
      break;
    case "B":
        var val = "ZZZ"
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = val;
  var text = document.getElementById("textField");
  text.style.display = "block";

}
<label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" value=""><br>

<label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" value=""><br><br>

<label for="test">Test</label>
<select id="test">
  <option value="A">AA</option>
  <option value="B">BB</option>
  <option value="C">CC</option>
</select><br><br>
<button class="button" onclick="fun()">Wihtout button?</button>
<div id="textField" style="display: none;"></div>

<span id="out0"></span><br><br>
<span id="out1"></span>




Please review the [tour] and [ask] pages - questions should limit themselves to a single question.   Either ask how to combine inputs without click or ask how to add a copy button (though this will have quite a few existing answers on SO already, so just search for that)

@fdomn-m, can you please link to such an answer, then? I have not found one doing this.

Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+copy+to+clipboard top answer as also provided by @LãNgọcHải is quite comprehensive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript/30810322#30810322

Here is a version using delegation
Note the copy function itself will not work at SO but will work in a JSFiddle and on your site
https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/hod6svum/
window.addEventListener('load', () => { // when page loads
  const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
  const textField = document.getElementById("textField");
  const select = document.getElementById("test");
  const copyButton = document.getElementById("copyButton");
  const out0 = document.getElementById("out0");
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault()); // stop submission
  copyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const textToCopy = textField.textContent;
    if (textToCopy.trim() === "") return; // nothing to copy
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy).then(() => {
      alert('Text copied to clipboard!');
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error('Failed to copy text: ', err);
    });

  });
  form.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    // create the output
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const output = Array.from(formData.entries()) // Convert to array
      .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`) // Format each entry
      .join('\n'); // Join with newlines
    textField.textContent = output; // Set the output
    if (tgt?.id === 'test') { // if the target has an ID and it is 'test'
      out0.textContent = tgt.value; // set the output
    }
  });
  // specific alternative to the above
  select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    out0.textContent = e.target.value; // Set the output
  });

})

.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  top: 0;
  width: 60%;
  max-height: 157px!important;
}

<form id="myForm">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value=""><br>

  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value=""><br><br>

  <label for="test">Test</label>
  <select id="test" name="test">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="A">AA</option>
    <option value="B">BB</option>
    <option value="C">CC</option>
  </select><br><br>
</form>
Out0:<span id="out0"></span><br/>
<div id="textField"></div> <button id="copyButton" type="button" class="button">Copy to clipboard</button>


But this IS the simpler version. Please update your question to reflect what you need. Right now https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/hod6svum/ does what you asked

Sure. See update - I updated the fiddle too

It will run on your server. It is an issue of permissions of the instance you are running. The execCommand is deprecated

@PeterSeliger - nice one with the console. I normally restrict the height.

While my initial <span id="out1"></span> does also output the test-id tag, your proposed solution does not. I have tried to re-write   const output = Array.from(formData.entries()) // Convert to array       .map(([key, value]) =>${key}: ${value}) // Format each entry       .join('\n'); // sucht that I can access the key of value=="test" to no avail. Can you please suggest a routine to do that?

I gave you two methods now - one is on any input, the other is on change specifically of the select. I also added a "please select" to have a way to trigger the select

You can listen to input event on the inputs, everytime those event get fired simply show the new texts


var fn = document.getElementById("fname");
var ln = document.getElementById("lname");
var test = document.getElementById("test");
fn.addEventListener('input', func)
ln.addEventListener('input', func)
test.addEventListener('input', func)

function func() {
  const out = ln.value + "," + fn.value + "," + test.value;
  document.getElementById("out0").innerHTML = out;

  const val = test.value == 'A' ? 'YYY' : test.value == 'B' ? 'ZZZ' : 'XXX'
  document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = val;
  
  var text = document.getElementById("textField");
  text.style.display = "block";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" value=""><br>

  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" value=""><br><br>

  <label for="test">Test</label>
  <select id="test">
    <option value="A">AA</option>
    <option value="B">BB</option>
    <option value="C">CC</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <div id="textField" style="display: none;"></div>

  <span id="out0"></span><br><br>
  <span id="out1"></span>

</body>

</html>




@NewToStats that's an entire different question, you should check this answer for information. It's quite long but cover all the methods, even the deprecated ones. IIRC the standard should be Clipboard API, you can use it like this: navigator.clipboard.writeText('some text to copy')

You'll be able to do that using JavaScript's addEventListener(<listener>, <object>) on the last mandatory element of your form. For example, run the function fun() whenever you have a change in the select element.
In your specific case, add document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("change", fun); after the closing curly bracket of your fun() function.
Then, remove the button.

@user27425627 I was the first to answer. Plus, it does solve the OP's problem.

Sorry, my bad, you're right - comment deleted. I'll delete this one too once you read it.
